# add attribute to element with the href link but without the #

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to add attribute to `li` with the href link but without the #
for example:

```
<ul id="menu-1" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item"><a href="#firstPage">first Page</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item"><a href="#secondPage">second Page</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item"><a href="#thirdPage">third Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

**will be**

```
<ul id="menu-1" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item" data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">first Page</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item" data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">second Page</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item" data-menuanchor="thirdPage"><a href="#thirdPage">third Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

here is the code that will add attribute to li

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
$('#menu-1 li').attr('data-menuanchor', '**here i need to add the href without #**')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to achieve that:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //get the url
  var oldUrl = $("#menu-item-1").children().attr("href");
  //remove # using String.prototype.replace()
  var url = oldUrl.replace(/#/, "");
  //add attribute data-menuanchor to li element
  $('#menu-1 li').attr('data-menuanchor', url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-1" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item"><a href="#firstPage">first Page</a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also in one line:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#menu-1 li').attr('data-menuanchor', $("#menu-item-1").children().attr("href").replace(/#/, ""));
});
```

Also to add the `data-menuanchor` to all `li` elements you need an iterator. Here an example using jquery [**.filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#menu-1 li').filter(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-menuanchor', this.children[0].hash.replace(/#/, ""));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-1" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item"><a href="#firstPage">first Page</a>

  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item"><a href="#secondPage">second Page</a>

  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item"><a href="#thirdPage">third Page</a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$(function(){
    $('li', $('#menu-1')).each(function(){
        $(this).attr('data-menuanchor', $('a', $(this)).attr('href').replace('#',''));
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uu5nbn7r/

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function($) {
  $('#menu-1 li').each(function(i, val){
     $(this).attr('data-menuanchor',$(this).find('a').attr('href').replace('#',''));
  });
});
```